# Blogging engine A to Z

Tags: .net, asp.net, blogs

I want to start writing my own blogs but have few queries before I start doing that.
I was recently reading David Hayden's article and he is under pain as the blog engine he is using is of dark ages and it doesn't go well with current technologies and interface.

I would like to know A to Z of getting started with one of the best Blog engine you have used so far and the one which is under constant development and upgrade.

Comment: Do you want to write your own blog *engine*, or do you just want to write a blog?

Comment: Just want to write a blog and so will use already developed blogger engine. I want to use the one which is upgraded constantly, so that I don't look like using dark age blog after few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either create your own or you use a .NET enabled blog like

- [dasBlog](http://www.dasblog.info/)
- [blogengine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)
- [Subtext](http://subtextproject.com/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
- [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) (Microsoft)

I've been using dasBlog since 2006 myself. Friends of mine are using one of the others and are also pleased with it. I suggest you simply check some of these out to see what fits for you.